# transparency in windows forms C#

Tags: c#, transparency

if the transparentkey property is used to make the top level form  transparent,it works  , but it also makes the main form click-throughable. I want the opposite of this, that the form becomes transparent, but is still able to recieve clicks. can this be done ?

Comment: Do you want the whole window transparent or just a bit of it?

Comment: How is your user supposed to be able to guess that the click doesn't actually go to what she clicked on?

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/scottlysle/XparentFormsCS10282007212944PM/XparentFormsCS.aspx) is een solution. The form is totaly transparent and still clickable.

Answer (score 0):

There is also

```
myform.Opacity = .75
```

.. which you can change as required. It may work better depending on your needs - you don't state whether its the whole form or only part of it you want transparent. Also, from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.transparencykey.aspx) on `TransparencyKey`:

> Any mouse actions, such as the click
>   of the mouse, that are performed on
>   the transparent areas of the form will
>   be transferred to the windows below
>   the transparent area.

.. so it would seem that wont help you at all.